# Collectionviewcell gets animated in ios10

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, ios10

I am using ios10 now, initially things were going fine but in ios10, collection view cells are loaded with animation from left to right.
Do anyone have faces the same issue? Kindly help.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context and any code you have already written. You've tagged "ios10-today-widget", but not how it's relevant?

Comment: code is working on all devices. So I think may be it's coz of ios10. Have remove it, it was mistakenly.